# Solve certain Lotka-Volterra's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling

I'm learning about Lotka-Volterra's model for predation in nature, to be said, the classic example of foxes and rabbits on a island. I understand where does the expression come from, and after substituting the different parameters to solve a "pretended real example", I got the following expression.
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
     P'(t) & = & 0.1P(t)\left(1-\frac{P(t)}{10000}\right)-0.005P(t)D(t)
  \\ P(0) & = & 2000
  \\ D'(t) & = & 0.00004P(t)D(t)-0.04D(t)
  \\ D(0) & = & 10
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Here, $P(t)$ and $D(t)$ are the population of preys (rabbits) and predators (foxes) respectively at time $t$.

My problem is that I don't know how to solve this kind of equation. I studied differential equations time ago but I had never seen one like this, involving two different functions. I've seen there has been people asking  questions about Lotka-Volterra also, but this one's different since I haven't found anyone including the term $\left(1-\frac{P(t)}{10000}\right)$ (this refers to the logistic aspect of rabbits population, since in my model I'm assuming the ecosystem has resources for a maximum of $10000$ rabbits at the same time, and leaves me with a NON LINEAR system of differential equations).

How can I solve this differential equation exactly? I'm interested in finding the exact expressions for $P(t)$ and $D(t)$ to plot them next, not in using numerical methods to find approximations. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is no exact solution, there is quite possibly a stable limit cycle around the unstable stationary point. So numerical solutions is the best you can get.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks! I'm researching online how to solve it numerically.